# Can't extend google api scope using google-api-client gem

Tags: ruby, google-analytics, google-api, sinatra

I followed the example provided for the google-api-ruby-client gem: https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client-samples/blob/master/calendar/calendar.rb

It works fine. So I wanted to use it with Google Analytics and made the following changes (everything else is the same as in the sample):

```
...
def analytics_api; settings.analytics; end
...

configure do
  ...

  client.authorization.scope = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics' # <- Here I added Analytics
  ]

  ...

  analytics = client.discovered_api('analytics', 'v3')
  set :analytics, analytics
end

...

get '/' do
  result = api_client.execute(:api_method => analytics_api.management.accounts.list,
                              :parameters => {},
                              :authorization => user_credentials)
  [result.status, {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}, result.data.to_json]
end
```

I also activated Google Analytics in the Google Developer Console API list (as I did for Calendar), and restarted the server.

But, when I check on `http://localhost:4567` (yes, I'm using Sinatra), I don't get the new authorisation request google page (for Google Analytics) and the following message is displayed:

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"insufficientPermissions","message":"Insufficient Permission"}],"code":403,"message":"Insufficient Permission"}}
```

It seems that the API doesn't take the new scope into consideration. It still works with Calendar, but not Analytics.

Any idea? Thanks.